# Good presentation software with smooth slide transition

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, presentation

I have tested the libre office impress and the openoffice presentation software and they are very good and do pretty much what I want but both of them have an issue with slide transition and animation, it's not very smooth enough , so is there anything i can add to them to make it much smoother , or is there any application out there that have a really smooth slideshow transition ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an application, but you can always look at prezi. It's online and if I remember correctly there is an iOS app. Used that for many presentations and the professors or people in the meeting loved it.

https://prezi.com/

Comment: I would suggest being careful with this, though. Consider if you'll have (fast) internet, and if it fits the presentation style you're making.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Calligra Suite:

https://www.calligra.org

The application is called 'Stage'.